# What are these long objects in Jakarta?

Tags: identify-this, jakarta

While browsing Google Maps, I found this [Jakarta](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Jakarta) neighboorhood ([coordinates: -6.100917, 106.920639](https://www.google.co.jp/maps/place/6%C2%B006'03.3%22S+106%C2%B055'14.3%22E)) with strange long shapes between the houses:

[image]

At first I thought it was floating logs/lumber among floating houses, but the picture below (the best of the 6 pictures of this place found on Google Maps) shows that:

- The houses are not floating, they are stilt houses, some are two floors high. This means that they can't move, and if the long shapes were lumber they would be very difficult to move.
- The long shapes themselves seem to be on stilts, 1 or 2 meters above sea level.

[image]

Question: What are these long shapes?

It seems unusual enough that it should warrant a visit.

Comment: They look like piers.

Answer (score 12):

I have found a similar place a kilometer further east ([coordinates](https://www.google.co.jp/maps/place/6%C2%B005'51.6%22S+106%C2%B055'55.2%22E)):

[image]

As for the place in the question, the long shapes are near the sea, seem to be kind of port of a harbour-like zone, but some are locked between houses so that they could hardly be piers.

Fortunately, this place has Google Street View. And here is what the street view looks like:

[image]

[image]

These are fish drying tables. This explains the proximity to a harbor, and the lack of a necessity for immediate sea access. Looks worth a visit for fish enthusiasts.